# How do I use callback functions for listeners in Nodejs without having to write inline?

Tags: node.js, performance, listener

So, the way Nodejs documents adding listeners is by using the `.on` functions, such as

```
...
var somevar_i_need_to_use = 5;
request.on('close', function handle_close() {
    console.log("Connection closed" +somevar_i_need_to_use);
});
...
```

And this will work fine, e.g. I can access the outer variable `somevar_i_need_to_use` fine. Without looking to much at the internals, I assume the equivalent way to not inlining the function is to write:

```
...
var somevar_i_need_to_use = 5;
request.addListener('close', handle_close(a_somevar_i_need_to_use));
...

function handle_close(a_variable) {
    console.log("Connection closed" +a_variable);
}
```

e.g. a named function. However, running this, I get an error:

```
   throw new TypeError('listener must be a function');
   ^

TypeError: listener must be a function
    at IncomingMessage.addListener (events.js:197:11)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:680:33)
    at handle_get_request (/root/wshub/wsh.js:84:9)
    at Server.internal_request_handler (/root/wshub/wsh.js:59:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:537:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:97:23)
```

Can someone tell me why this happens?
I would assume this is equal to writing it inline? I want to declare my functions like this for performance, modularity and readability reasons.

Comment: You're calling `handle_close` and then passing its result (`undefined`) into `addListener`, not passing the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing this error because you are passing result of whatever handle_close function returns as listener, which in this case is undefined. To achieve desired behavior, try something like this:

```
var somevar_i_need_to_use = 5;
request.addListener('close', create_close_handler(a_somevar_i_need_to_use));


function create_close_handler(a_variable) {
    return function named_handler(...listener_args) {
        console.log("Connection closed" +a_variable);
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually takes into account any variables that might be declared in the outer scope which I might need to use. This is what I need because outer scope has several variables i need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you add a listener, just use the function name with no arguments:

```
request.addListener('close', handle_close);

var handler_variable = 0;
function handle_close(arg_variablle) {
  /* do something with arg_variable and handler_variable ... */
}
```

If you call the function (by using `handle_close(arguments)`) like you do, it will not add the function as a listener, but the *return value* of the function. This is most often not what you want.

Comment: Oh thats right, by using the `handle_close(args)` im *calling* the function, which is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: How would I go about using this "design" to pass an amount of variables into the listener? how does the `handle_close` method know what parameters to take?

Comment: @enrm Variables declared outside the function (e.g., in the global scope) are accessible from within the function and can "just be used". The `handle_close` method is given parameters when it is called by `request`; which parameters it gets is most often documented in the function's (in this case `request.addListener`) documentation.

Comment: the problem is if the variable is not a global variable, for example a user id which is unique per request ( and thus per listener ) How do I account for this?